# Google App Engine (Python) - Datastore is duplicating entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bottle

I am using the Python SDK for Google App Engine, and bottle.

Running something simple like this to set up some entities to work with:

```
@bottle.route('/test')
def testing():
    Statistic(team_id = 2, qty_customers = 600).put()
    Statistic(team_id = 3, qty_customers = 5).put()
    return "Done."
```

Statistic looks like this:

```
class Statistic(ndb.Model):
    team_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    qty_customers = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

I would expect it to create one entity for each of those, and add them to the datastore. It creates two copies of each and adds them to the datastore.

How can I make the code only add one entity?

Why is it creating two?

Edit:
To clarify, I am running the testing() function once, and it creates 4 entities. Two duplicates of each.

Comment: Can you add your `Statistic` class to the question? Does it inherit from `db.Model` or from `ndb.Model`?

Comment: Edited my post show the Statistic class. I am using the ndb model.

Comment: Why did you not put function `testing` inside this class as a `@staticmethod`?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean, could you explain?

Comment: If you do not use a key, you will put a new Statistic with a new auto-generated key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the old DB (`db.Model`), you would have to specify `key_name` when creating an instance.

In the new DB (`ndb.Model`), you need to specify `id`, otherwise an incremented integer is chosen.

So calling function `testing` twice yields four different `Statistic` instances with IDs 1, 2, 3 and 4.

If you explicitly specify a different ID for each `Statistic` instance, then you will get only two instances.

---

I believe that in your case, you might as well remove the `team_id` field:

```
class Statistic(ndb.Model):
    qty_customers = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

Then, specify a unique ID for every `Statistic` instance that you create:

```
def testing():
    Statistic(id = 2, qty_customers = 600).put()
    Statistic(id = 3, qty_customers = 5).put()
```

BTW, I think that it is recommended to use string IDs rather than integer IDs:

```
def testing():
    Statistic(id = '2', qty_customers = 600).put()
    Statistic(id = '3', qty_customers = 5).put()
```

**UPDATE:**

Even if you're calling function `testing` in your application only once, GAE often creates and destroys **the application instance itself**. So each time a new instance of your application is created, a new pair of `Statistic` instances are also created. If these instances are not already in the database, then they are added to it when you call function `put` (and that's why you need to specify an ID for each instance).

Comment: So adding an id = 'something' fixed the problem of duplicates being created. Why does this fix it? I don't understand why it was creating a copy beforehand.

Comment: @sifRAWR: As I explained in the answer, if you **don't** specify `id`, then an incremented integer is chosen as default. So when you call function `testing` twice, you get four different `Statistic` instances with IDs 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: I am not calling the function testing twice, I am calling it once. From one call it is creating 4 instances.

Comment: Appengine does not nor ever has randomly create multiple entities. Put some logging in/around that method, I bet you will find it is being called twice.

Comment: Perhaps, but you don't know for sure how many instances of your **application** are created by GAE. Sometimes it creates several instances. If each one of them calls `testing`, then you get multiple `Statistic` instances. Perhaps I should add this in the answer...

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks, that makes more sense. How can I avoid this problem? If I want a function to only be called once.

Comment: @sifRAWR: You cannot force calling this function only once, and you should not hope to do so either. Remember, when a new instance of your application is created, it's as if you're "starting over". What you DO have to take care of, is making sure that your application is always **stateless**. In other words, do not rely on any variable in memory. Pretty much everything has to be stored in the DB and loaded from the database at `__init__`. In function `testing`, simply use `id` (as you already have), in order to prevent the replication of these instances.

Comment: @TimHoffman I just added logging.info("Statistic created.") and it only ran the function once, but it still created copies.

Comment: Clearly something odd is going on with your setup.  Otherwise everyone using python, ndb and appengine would be having spurious entities created.  Are you running in dev or live ?

Comment: WHere is your logging done. And are your clearing the datastore after every run ?  If you are not explicitly setting the keys and you don't clear the datastore you will accumulate records.

Comment: @TimHoffman Yeah, I figured that it might be a common error and posting on here someone would immediately realize and tell me what I'm doing wrong. This is on a dev server. The environment is not being cleared as there is already data on there I want to keep. I am not running the same function more than once though, I change it each time to add different data. Or, if I was running the same one to test, I manually delete the entries from the datastore. Adding the keys fixed it from creating duplicates, I'm not sure I understand why but I guess that doesn't really matter.

Comment: @sifRAWR, here is the update I added to the answer. I think it should explain the problem: "Even if you're calling function `testing` in your application only once, GAE often creates and destroys the application instance itself. So each time a new instance of your application is created, a new pair of `Statistic` instances are also created. If these instances are **not already** in the database, then they are added to it when you call function `put` (and that's why you need to specify an ID for each instance)".

Comment: @Tim Hoffman: OK, sorry, whoever did that, did not leave any note on this, so I figured it was you... Oh, I just noticed you were making it up for me :) LOL, thanks.

Comment: @Tim Hoffman  ("Otherwise everyone using python, ndb and appengine would be having spurious entities created."  I'm experiencing this exact problem and I've been debugging for two days trying to figure out what the deal is. It's not the code, it's App engine. App engine is calling my load handler twice, despite me calling it once, and emptying out the database before each call to the load handler is not preventing entities from being duplicated for no reason at all.)

Comment: @jill Russek  One of the design principals for well designed appengine projects utilising the datastore is idempotent routines.  Especially when you start using tasks.  You are working in a distributed environment so it is possible something can be called multiple times. This isn't the datastore but your operating environment.  There are many different ways of guarding against concurrent updates, involving transactions, rollfoward transactions etc...  Is your handler being called twice in the same instance or in two separate instances. I suggest you start a new question in SO